# How to send video streaming to WOWZA server using RTSP from iOS app?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avfoundation, video-encoding, wowza

I am new in capturing video(`AVFoundation`) and WOWZA server.

I have checked many solutions but didn't find any tutorials or libraries on "How to work with WOWZA server using RTSP". I found one project [VideoCore](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) on GitHub but it works only on RTMP. They have suggested [answer](https://github.com/GuilhermeMedeiros/react-native-videocore/issues/3) on the RTSP problem, USE live555 protocol. But i hardly understand c++ code.

**My Question:**

- How do i get video stream from AVFoundation? Right now i am getting file not stream data using `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`:

`captureOutput(_: didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:, fromConnections: error:)`

But i need stream output data so i can send to WOWZA server.

- How to convert video to encoded h.264 stream?
- How to integrate live555 library to VideoCapture class for generate RTSP URL?
- How to send that video to WOWZA using RTSP protocol?

Please, Suggest me with any library or sample code in your answer.

Comment: In a quick look, I found the Encoder project  (https://github.com/OpenWatch/H264-RTSP-Server-iOS).  Granted it looks to publish on the device and you'd need to ingest it from Wowza, but it does make use of the AVFoundation library of which may be useful in your development.

Answer (score 0):

using [iOS-Video-Encoding](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2013/02/20/iOS-Video-Encoding.html) Video Encoder library for encoding frame in h264 format and then send to Live555 RTSPClient. Hope this will helps you. Thanks punita

Answer (score 0):

You can stream RTSP from iOS app using the mobile SDK with Wowza Streaming Engine software. Disclaimer: I work at Wowza.

1. Configure your live stream by opening Streaming Engine Manager
2. In the Streaming Engine Manager, click the Applications tab at the top of the page.
3. In the Applications contents panel, click Live, and then click Edit.
4. In Playback options, select all you would like. RTSP/RTP is an option.
5. Complete remaining security steps.

To see supporting docs to test the stream, please go here. Hope this helps!

https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-set-up-live-streaming-using-an-rtsp-rtp-based-encoder

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, I'll edit and provide more details.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a easier route, you could look at Red5 Pro's offerings. It doesn't use Wowza or expect that you fully understand iOS dev. There's also a blog post / walk-thru for creating your own [Periscope](https://blog.red5pro.com/build-periscope-in-10-minutes/) type app, which is what I assume you're trying to create?